# android:typeface setting don't work in Lollipop

Tags: android, textview, typeface

I have a font in asset folder of my project. I set it to a textview in my layout.
But it doesn't work on Lollipop. There it displays text with default font.

Answer (score 0):

Add your font file in `assets` folder and set it in `TextView`

```
Typeface myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(), "YOUR_FONT.ttf");
YOUR_TEXT_VIEW.setTypeface(myTypeface);
```

Comment: i did it .please read my question again.i have problem only with Lollipop

Comment: Zohreh, any fix for this issue? I'm facing the same problem with Lolipop